# Cat keeps peeing/pooping in the basement

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training, urination

I have a 12 year old cat, who has been peeing/pooping in our basement. She has done this before a while ago, but stopped the habit after changing her litter. Then, this past summer, we took down our shed and much of it's contents are currently in our garage where her litter box is. Soon after, she started refusing to use the litter box. My mother got tired of cleaning up after her and put her outside for the summer. (She is an indoor/outdoor cat.)

We've recently let her back in due to the cold weather (after 4-5 months I'd say) and us being out of town for Thanksgiving. It was easier to get someone to feed her that way if she's in the house.

At first she seemed fine and had no issue. We were more careful to clean her litter box more often. And coming back from Thanksgiving, we found pee/poo in the house again.

We don't want the litter box in the house, because she is usually messy with it and there really isn't any convenient space in the house for it. I don't think it's a urinary infection, because she hadn't gotten back into the habit until we tore down the shed. We aren't going to get her checked out, because it's expensive and we are pretty positive it's the stuff in the garage.

I am just not sure what to do anymore to correct this. She'll get put in the garage for the winter if she doesn't stop this act. I think come this next summer we'll put up a new shed, but until then I'm not sure what I can do. But if this keeps up, she'll be kicked out of the house again.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like the things from the shed are making her uncomfortable/spooked. They may have smells from other animals. Put a litter box somewhere else in the house. Your pet is a member of the family and needs a bathroom space where she feels safe  even if it's not convenient, it's part of being a cat owner. I use a top entry litter box like "Clever Cat" to cut down on the mess and litter spread. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Either clean up the stuff in the garage at all or get a storage locker until the new shed is complete.  Also, you can look into getting some litter attractant like [this one](http://amzn.to/2glCfT1).  It's basically a special kind of litter that is formulated to attract cats by scent and make them want to eliminate in the appropriate spot.  Other logistical options include a [top entry litter box](http://amzn.to/2glCkG9) or [extended entry enclosed litter boxes](http://amzn.to/2fENy9t), which will virtually eliminate any dust or mess.

Locking the cat in the garage alone all winter is only going to make her crazy, and she may become destructive in other ways.  I second other respondents in saying you need to take your cat to the vet and get her checked out.  Even if it seems like nothing is wrong, you aren't a doctor and may be missing something.

**If you can't afford to give your cat proper veterinary care, then you can't afford to have a cat.**

*Note: I'm not sure where you live, but I'm in one of the most expensive cities in the world and a visit to the vet (with shots and blood or fecal tests) rarely runs over $200.  There are also clinics and animal care organizations which provide inexpensive vet care if you are having a hard time managing the expense.*